# Getting ID of facebook comments plugin

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, facebook-comments

I would like to get comments from a facebook plugin via FQL so that I can limit and order the number of comments I receive as using the graph API call:

https://graph.facebook.com/comments?ids=[myurl]

syntax is really inefficient when there are large numbers of comments involved.

I have had to add some underscores to urls as I don't have enough rep to post more than 2 links.

Ideally I would like to use FQL like this:

```
SELECT id,app_id, object_id,comment_count,parent_id,text,time from comment 
    where object_id = '10150322917810312' and time > 1387795068 ORDER BY time desc
```

The problem comes in finding the object_id that I should use here.

When I try using:

```
select id,url,site,type from object_url 
   where url = '_http://www.mecenat.se/studentrabatter/datorer-och-telefoni/datorer/apple'
```

I receive:

```
{
  "id": 245493548833513,
  "url": "http://www.mecenat.se/studentrabatter/datorer-och-telefoni/datorer/apple",
  "site": "www.mecenat.se",
  "type": "page"
}
```

But the object returned here does not have any comments.

Using the Graph API call

https://graph.facebook.com/comments?ids=http://www.mecenat.se/studentrabatter/datorer-och-telefoni/datorer/apple

I can see that the id of the comments plugin seems to be the prefix of the comment_id - in this case **10150322917810312**

When I then do another FQL call:

```
select id,url,site,type from object_url  where id = 10150322917810312
```

I receive:

```
{
  "id": "10150322917810312",
  "url": "http://www.mecenat.se/studentrabatter/datorer-och-telefoni/datorer/apple",
  "site": "www.mecenat.se",
  "type": "profile"
}
```

Why don't I receive this 'profile' result when I use url as parameter?

When I use

```
select id,url,site,type from object_url 
    where url = '_http://www.mecenat.se/studentrabatter/datorer-och-telefoni/datorer/apple' and type = 'page'
```

I get a result back, but when I use

```
select id,url,site,type from object_url 
    where url = '_http://www.mecenat.se/studentrabatter/datorer-och-telefoni/datorer/apple' and type = 'profile'
```

then I don't get anything back.

Obviously I can use the graph api call and parse the result to work out the comments object id and then use this in fql later, but I would like to have a more solid solution in order to find my object_id.

Any ideas?